# Postgres - DB Design & Spring-Data-JPA query related suggestion required

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

***Hello Friends,***

I have a kind of requirement like, `Student` & `Question` are `entities`.
Both `Entity` are in `many-to-many` *relation*.

I would like to *represent* my **idea** is something likewise(refer below **screen-shot**. please correct me if any **improvement** is possible).
[image]

**I would like to know from you guys is that,**

> 1) is the above mentioned DB-design is good ? is there any improvement
>   then let me know.

*And second one is related to query(`JPQL`),*

> 2) it's most important, in `spring-data-jpa`, how would I implement in
>   such a way so that, even though user has not answered question then
>   also, those question needs to reflect under user-profile page that
>   this question is still not answered. Refer below **screen-shot** about
>   an expectation of this(second one) **question**.

[image]

***Any help would be really appreciable!!***

Comment: Are you going to allow more than one answer to a question by a student? That might affect your design.

Comment: @Alan Thanks for replying. No, per student per question 1-answer only. It might be possible question what I asked may sounds likewise. but never ever will allowing students to admit more than 1-answer per question. however they can modify it as many time as they want.

Comment: Then you will need to put a unique index on the student_id/question_id combination. Also consider whether any of your questions require standardised answers. If there is a need to restrict certain questions to certain answers then you will need a lot more structure, but without that, this looks ok.

Comment: Also consider referential integrity - decide what is to happen if you attempt to delete a student with answers or an answered question.